# Текст при whitespace=nowrap изменяет цвет фона только в той части, которая не обрезается при whitespace=normal

Tags: javascript, css, прокрутка, цвета

Текст находится в элементе li внутри иерархического дерева. Дерево находится внутри элемента div.

Для элемента div в css-файле описано свойство `overflow:scroll`. Элементам li при их создании (раскрытии дерева) скриптом присваивается свойство `whitespace="nowrap"`. Так что текст в li показывается одной строкой, каким бы длинным он ни был, а ширина проматываемого по горизонтали элемента div постоянна.

Все корректно до тех пор, пока я не начинаю javascript-ом менять цвет фона для текста (элемента li). Цвет меняется только для части текста - от левого края до того символа, который последним помещается в div без промотки. т.е после которого при `whitespace="normal"` пойдет перенос строки. А все, что правее, остаётся прежним цветом.

Кто виноват? Что делать?

Гугл не помог.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Вы имеете в виду код? Он не в одном месте. Одна часть кода генерится яваскриптом, другая - в html, третья - в css. Отовсюду дергать? Я указал свойства (scroll, nowrap), которые, на мой взгляд, имеют значение.

Comment: ну, без кода сложно вам дать ответ который был бы прям ответом .... лучше было бы, что бы вы воспроизвели это все на простом примере. Представить в чем проблема по объяснению на самом деле не сложно, но с примером кода было бы проще работать.

Comment: Хорошо. Я понял. А если вы представляете, в чем проблема, то (до тех пор, пока я не собрался надергать из кусочков цельный, воспроизводимый код) могли бы вы хотя бы приблизительно сориентировать меня "куда копать"?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так должен выглядеть минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример ))
А решением вашей проблемы будет задание списку `display: inline-block;`:

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.list_item {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
    <li class="list_item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! )

Comment: @aguilar, ну тогда кликните по галке слева вверху ответа ;)

Comment: Уже кликал; сайт говорит, моей репутации недостаточно (